# Install AUR packages during installation

Tags: archlinux

I want to reinstall my system on a new computer from an backup. So I wrote a script which reinstalls all packages from a list and restores a backup, but one point is missing:

I also want to install packages from AUR, but I can not find a way how to install these packages.
First problem is that you are not allowed to build packages if you are root.
I could build a workaround for single packages with "su nobody", but I don't see a way how to use an AUR helper (like trizen) for packages which have dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Try using package managers such as paru or yay to install AURs. If not just download the AUR directly from GitHub and run their install script.

Comment: Build them directly is no alternative for me, because some of the packages have AUR dependencies, which I will not resolve by hand.
If have tried trizen, and it has the same problem as makepkg, do you think that paru or yay work under root?

Comment: Ohh I misunderstood your question then. I don't think paru and yay works under root, though have you tried to use something like time shift to backup and transfer the system settings and files over? Not sure if it still works as its been quite some time since I've used it.

Comment: Also installing packages under root is not recommended, why not write a script that installs the AURs under a non-root environment? Even with without a script you can just install multiple AURs by doing ```paru -S package1 package2 package3``` which can easily be copy pasted since you already have the list of packages.

Comment: Because I am working in the installer and I have no non-root user, which has sudo configured.

Comment: Hmm I guess one workaround could be trying to build in a chroot environment (not really sure if it works since you have no user), you should go read up more on this before trying it out or wait for someone else with more experience to help you out and see if there are other ways.

Comment: I am already in a chroot environment but there is no non-root user configured for sudo, so it does not help.

Comment: Hmm I have no idea then, best wishes for resolving your issue soon!

Comment: By the way if you are still getting no replies you should go to the arch linux forum and try asking there.